# What is a difference between traditional loop and for-each loop?

Tags: java

I wonder if there is a difference between these:

```
ArrayList<Example> list = new ArrayList<Example>
```

1-)

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    list.get(i).doSomething();
}
```

2-)

```
for(Example example : list) {
    example.doSomething();
}
```

If there is not any difference which one is more common or efficient?

Comment: Difference in what sense?

Comment: Premature optimization: Don't. Just... Don't. If you don't have a speed problem, don't solve it. In 99,9% of all cases, you will not notice a difference between the two - except the obvious, with one you have an index (and no iterator) and it only works on methods with a get(x) method, while the other you have no index, an iterator and it works with any collection.

Comment: The second one is more efficient. Because every .get(i) starts a random access search.

Comment: @Reinard Potentially yes, depending on the list being iterated through. The `ArrayList` in the example has no speed difference, but a `LinkedList` would show noticeable differences.

Comment: @Kayaman it all depends on the exact case which is running ofc.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I agree premature optimisation is very bad. But it doesn't mean that we have to write bad code in the first place. If you are using a `LinkedList`, you should use a for-each loop instead of using a traditional one, justifying it with saying "no premature optimisations". Spending 3-5 seconds on thinking upfront about such small things doesn't hurt as much as a whole week of profiling in the future.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak You should **always** use a for-each loop, unless you need the index for some reason. (Or in Java 8, you can use streams.) And not because it's faster (it usually isn't) but because it's easier to read.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Traditional loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    list.get(i).doSomething();
}
```

- allows to modify the list, e.g.:

  - you can add extra element at the end of list and it will be also iterated through
- you know the index

  - can be used to refer to another list of the same size
  - can be used to refer to previous/next element
- efficient only in `RandomAccess` lists

  - in case of `LinkedList` in every iteration of the loop, `get(i)` will have to iterate over all elements starting from `head/tail` to `i`
- works only with `List` since `List#get(int)` is used
- error prone, a lot of things that can go wrong, e.g.:

  - `i = 0;` instead of `int i = 0;` - will refer to variable declared before the loop, possible side effects outside of the loop
  - `>` instead of `<` - loop will not execute
  - `j++` instead of `i++` - infinite loop
  - `.get(j)` instead of `.get(i)` - will always get the same element

### For-each loop

```
for (Example example : list) {
    example.doSomething();
}
```

- does not allow to modify the list

  - trying to do so will most likely result in `ConcurrentModificationException`
- you don't know the index of the element

  - you cannot refer to previous/next element
- efficient in all cases because uses `Iterator` specific for the collection

  - efficient in case of `LinkedList`
- works not only with every `Collection`, but with every `Iterable` since `Iterable#iterator()` is used

  - you can easily replace `List` with a `Set` - no changes to the loop required
  - you can easily replace with your own class, it just has to implement `Iterable`
- more robust (less code, fewer special characters)

### Summary

`for-each` loop wins with a score 3 : 2.

The only reason to use a traditional loop is when:

- the index of element is required, or
- the list has to be modified

Answer (score 3):

They are basically the same, but for-each (the second one) has certain **restrictions**.

1. It can be used for **accessing** the array elements but not for **modifying** them.
2. It is not **usable** for loops that must iterate over
   multiple collections **in parallel**—for example, to compare the elements of two arrays.
3. It can be used only for a single element access and cannot be used to compare successive elements in an array. It is a ***forward-only*** iterator. If you want to access only a few elements of the array, you would need to use the traditional for loop.

Comment: @Point 1: you can modify the array elements by calling mutable methods. (or you need to specify, what you mean with "modify") I guess what you mean is that one cannot modify the array (or `Iterable`) itself.

Answer (score 1):

The second one works with every type of (potentially unordered) [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), as it doesn't rely on random access, i.e. `get(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

`for(:)` statement is a read-only loop. You cannot change a collection within this loop. Also you cannot use more than one element.

The traditional `for` statement doesn't have such limits.