# Remove User from list of users in java

Tags: java

I'm new to java, so please excuse me if my explanation is poor but I have a list :

```
private LinkedList<User> users= new LinkedList<User>();
```

and a method removeUser:

```
private void removeUser() {
        System.out.println("All Users: ");
        viewUsers();
        System.out.print("Please enter the ID of the user to be removed: ");
        int choice = In.nextInt();
        for (User user : users){ 
            if (users.contains(choice)) { 
                users.remove(choice); 
            } 

        }
    }
```

Now when I run the code it successfully prints out everything. Yet when I check the list contents, nothing has changed and I'm unsure of what I have done wrong with the removal part of the code.

Comment: Does `viewUsers()` print the list?

Comment: @Aniox yep, it prints the list correctly

Comment: So you didn't print it.

Comment: @Aniox Even if I print it after it still shows the user in the account

Comment: what are the member variables for the `user` object (that is the type of your linked list)?  I assume that object has a `user id` field that is an integer.  If thats the case then you probably should update your inner if statement to say `if (users.getID() == choice)` then proceed with the rest of your code.

Comment: Few problems: (1) `if (users.contains(choice))` is checking if list that contains objects of type User also contains some `int` which will never be evaluated to true. You probably wanted something more like `if(user.getID == choice)`. (2) `users.remove(choice);` will try to remove element at *position* `choice` in list which you are currently iterating over, not with ID==choice. (3) Since it will also modify list you are currently iterating over you may face `ConcurrentModificationException`. What you are after is probably something like `users.removeIf(user->user.getID()==choice)`.

Comment: **LIfe lesson**:  you wrote `for (User user : users)`, but you didn't use `user` anywhere inside the loop. Normally when you write a `for-each` loop it's because you want to _do something_ with each item of the collection you're iterating; that's you didn't do anything with `user` is a warning sign that something isn't quite right.

Comment: It’s not a full answer to your question, but I think it’s very helpful: [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing objects in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution: if you want to use lambda and streams to remove first User with corresponding ID.

```
private void removeUser() {
    System.out.println("All Users: ");
    viewUsers();
    System.out.print("Please enter the ID of the user to be removed: ");
    int choice = In.nextInt();
    
    users.stream()
         .filter(user->user.getId() == choice)
         .findFirst()
         .ifPresent(users::remove);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I’d prefer the `users.removeIf(user -> user.getID() == choice)` from the comment by Pshemo, though. Feel free to include it as an option in your answer if you like.

Comment: It is tested .. it does not cause `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: OK, I made a mistake by not noticing that when you call `.findFirst()` it is stream's *terminal operation* which ends stream processing and returns `Optional<User>`. This means that calling `.ifPresent(users::remove)` will not throw `ConcurrentModificationException` (as stream processing ended). +1 but still IMO 
`users.removeIf(user->user.getId() == choice)` is more intuitive here.

Comment: Agreed... its concise and cleaner.. however `removeIf` will remove all element with matching predicate. deletion will go for O(n). however `findFirst` will exit once we find first element. so its faster on average.

Comment: Had to edit something if I wanted to change my incorrect vote :) Anyway `users::remove` will invoke List#remove which usually also need to iterate over entire list in case element exist more than once which makes it `O(n)`.

Comment: Oh ya... still the list inside... thanks for clarification..

Answer (score -1):

If you want remove some item from list you can't use for-each loop. Refer: [What is a difference between traditional loop and for-each loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582050/what-is-a-difference-between-traditional-loop-and-for-each-loop)

I think you need same:

```
 private void removeUser() {
    System.out.println("All Users: ");
    viewUsers();
    System.out.print("Please enter the ID of the user to be removed: ");
    int choice = In.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){ 
        User user = users.get(i);
        if (user.contains(choice)) { 
            users.remove(i); // remove at index i
        } 

    }
}
```

Hope can help you!